# Deciphering smartctl results

Tags: usb, hard-disk, smartctl, sata, smart

I'm trying to use an internal 2.5" HDD to serve as my external storage media and for backups. This HDD had been previously on a Windows machine for a long time before some of my files became corrupted, and so I simply changed it for an SSD. CrystalDiskInfo reports the drive's health as 'good', however, HDDScan shows a warning for "UltraDMA CRC Errors".

This is the results of running `smartctl -a` on it:

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-w10-21H2] (sf-7.3-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Mobile HDD
Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
Firmware Version: SDM1
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 169) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   072   051   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       15037148
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   065   065   020    Old_age   Always       -       36007
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   080   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       22014115380
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       55 (236 20 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   092   020    Old_age   Always       -       56
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       3990
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       30067195949
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   068   049   040    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 29/32)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       197
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   064   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       73637
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (0 18 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   051   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       12591 (154 139 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       98336960706
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       114926523300
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 3475 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 3475 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29 hours (1 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 88 7d f4 09  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x09f47d88 = 167017864

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 88 7d f4 49 00      00:38:49.208  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 80 7d f4 49 00      00:38:49.195  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 b0 a8 21 49 00      00:38:49.182  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 a8 a8 21 49 00      00:38:49.181  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 a0 a8 21 49 00      00:38:49.181  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 3474 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29 hours (1 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 80 7d f4 09  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x09f47d80 = 167017856

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 80 7d f4 49 00      00:38:46.657  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 78 7d f4 49 00      00:38:46.625  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:46.615  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:46.605  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:38:46.578  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 3473 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29 hours (1 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 78 7d f4 09  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x09f47d78 = 167017848

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 78 7d f4 49 00      00:38:44.127  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 70 7d f4 49 00      00:38:44.095  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:44.085  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:44.076  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:38:44.049  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 3472 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29 hours (1 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 70 7d f4 09  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x09f47d70 = 167017840

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 70 7d f4 49 00      00:38:41.598  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 68 7d f4 49 00      00:38:41.566  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.556  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.547  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:38:41.520  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 3471 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29 hours (1 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 68 7d f4 09  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x09f47d68 = 167017832

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 68 7d f4 49 00      00:38:39.013  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 60 7d f4 49 00      00:38:38.987  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:38.977  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:38.968  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:38:38.941  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%        22         282912
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%        20         282912
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%        18         282912
# 4  Conveyance offline  Completed: read failure       90%        18         282912
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       80%        18         282912
# 6  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%        17         282912
# 7  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%         2         64400520
# 8  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%         2         64400520
# 9  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%         2         64400520
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9245         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4741         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4667         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Which is bit confusing to me. The drive is attached to my computer via USB (adaptor) which has no brand name on it, but `smartctl` reveals it to be "USB JMicron". Is this "USB JMicron" adaptor causing the "UltraDMA CRC Errors" or other problems?

As I'm not sure what had caused the then data corruption, I am wondering if this drive is actually safe and reliable based on the info from `smartctl`. Any help with deciphering the diagnostic info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

USB - sATA : such device has to translate the USB command set to sATA command set. The most important and most frequent
are command for read sector (block) and write it. Some USB/sATA device do not translate the other commands and hence `smartctl` and `hdparm` cannot get service information. Some (JMicron included) do translate all commands. Newer `smartctl` version can autodetect the chipset and use it.

With `smartctl` you can either start a disk auto-test either just collect the saved logged information.
For magnetic disk the `194 Temperature` is important, because the magnetic properties can irreversibly degrade if the temperature is close to Currie Temperature. It is safe to keep the working temperature under 40 Celsius degree. (less is better). Some HD remember the temperature history, too.

The harddisk usually has some reserved sectors (blocks) to be used if some part of mg. surface is not in a good condition. Number of such sectors is `5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct`. This numer, if less than 100, must not signalise the unusable disk. It may be a little more loaded while jumping to the reserved sectors. More dangerous is a if such number grows in time. In such case it is not recommended to use it.

The `197 Current_Pending_Sector` can be more annoying because the disk controller cannot confirm the sector content with its CRC. Some times such sector may be created accidentally, and can dismiss after rewriting it, but in some cases it is preceding the reallocating.

I am really not sure, what Seagate meant with `199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count` but while the magnetic head is flying over the mg surface the seek error simply happen, just as the read errors which represents les then 0.01% of reads.

SSDs do not degrade too much with high temperature, and usually do not dissipate too much power. They also have some spare blocks (not sectors, much more greater blocks), as the block need to be erased and written at once. The SSD controller does a lot of juggling with the blocks, because each write operations cuts its life. Hence you must watch the `241 Total_LBAs_Written`.

You can see a TBW parametr of SSD what is acronym for **Tera Bytes Write** .

If you divide this number with the SSD capacity you can see that one block can be written less than 100 times at cheap SSD and cca 500 times at better. Only SSD for servers can overlive more than 10000 writes of one block.

My opinion: Your disk looks to be in a good condition (not excellent), but keep on mind that its heads were flying nearly one and half year, so I recommend to buy an external box and use this disk for backup or archive. Before the next use you may zero the whole disk and check the `smartctl -x` again. If there will be no or minor changes only, OK.

Comment: Is there any way to find more about the JMicron chip inside the adaptor without tearing it apart?

Comment: There is jmicron.com/products page.

Answer (score 1):

Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled — for some drive this setting causes SMART values to not be updated properly, so consider enabling it.

UDMA CRC errors just happen sometimes. If this value is high and keeps rising, you might have to replace the SATA cable or port (or the entire USB enclosure).

It looks like the Power on Hours counter has either overflowed (normal for long running drives) or was deliberately reset to 0 (sometimes happens with drives sold on Ebay).

The real problem with this drive is that it currently has read errors in selftest; altogether it seems like this is an older drive which now shows signs of failure (already lost data for those read failures).

If there is any data of this drive you still need to recover, `ddrescue` would be the next step.

If you don't care about data on the drive, you could run a badblocks test in destructive write mode (the non-destructive one does not overwrite read errors and thus does not help with reallocating sectors) or overwrite it using some other tool.

And then check SMART again and run another selftest.

Either way, I would not put much trust in this drive anymore.

Comment: I can't enable Auto Offline Data Collection. Running `smartctl --offlineauto=on` says "SMART Automatic Timers not supported" and "SMART Automatic Offline Testing Enabled every four hours.", but running `smartctl -c` still shows it as disabled.

Comment: Regarding the Power on Hours counter, I remember some time ago it was a very large number, but now it's so small, so I guess it has overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

You've got just 3 such errors, I wouldn't worry about that.

What I'd worry about however is Command_Timeout which is crazy high (30,067,195,949) but if you don't have any perceivable slowdowns, there's no need to worry. It doesn't mean the drive is dying but could indicate some e.g. interface issues.